# How can I get the launchctl.out file on daily on MacOS?

Tags: mac-osx, stdout, launchctl

I am new with MacOS.
And I am not the one who made this plist file.
All I just findout somehow this plist file makes this shell script avery 60seconds.
I am just familiar with CRON on linux system, but not this LaunchAgents on MacOS.
This is the plist file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.apps.fastlanebuild</string>

  <key>Program</key>
  <string>/opt/homebrew/var/www/fastlane.sh</string>

  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>60</integer>

  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>

  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/opt/homebrew/var/www/log/ios_build_launchctl.out</string>

  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/opt/homebrew/var/www/log/ios_build_launchctl_err.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The problem is all the output is added up in one file.
How can I get the output as daily bases?

Is there any way to do it in plist file?
And if so, how can I apply it? (don't know the right command on MacOS)